# Calculated column, one column is what percent of another column?

Tags: 2013, calculated-column

I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out the calculation in a calculated column.  Here's what I've got - I have two NUMBER columns (column A and Column B). What I want is to calculate "Column A is ?? Percent of Column B?"
What would my calculation be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the formula given below.

```
=IF(ISERROR(ColumnA/ColumnB),"",ColumnA/ColumnB)
```

Result is shown in the image below (here percentage is - column1 is percent of Column2 shown in `PercentColumn`)

[image]